# How to create a new commit off of an old revision?

Tags: version-control, dvcs, bazaar

I'm new to bazaar, but very familiar with Git.  I'm trying to understand the basics.

Suppose I have a branch whose history looks like this:

```
* 3 bar
|
* 2 foo
|
* 1 initial commit
```

I have a series of patches that I want to turn into commits, but they're based on an old revision.  I want to create the commits off of the old revision and then merge the results back in.  The resulting graph should look like this:

```
* 4 merge 
|\
| * 2.1.3 apply patch #3
| |
| * 2.1.2 apply patch #2
| |
| * 2.1.1 apply patch #1
| |
* | 3 bar
|/
* 2 foo
|
* 1 initial commit
```

How do I do this with `bzr`?

With Git, I'd do something like this:

```sh
git checkout -b import-patches master^
for p in 1 2 3; do
    git apply --index /path/to/"${p}".patch
    git commit -m "apply patch #${p}"
done
git checkout master
git merge import-patches
git branch -d import-patches
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Git, Bzr has a model of using one working directory per branch instead of using one working directory per repository (unless you use co-located branches). The basic workflow for your example is roughly the same:

First, branch off the current branch to a new directory `../import-patches`. You can use negative revision numbers or the `last:n` notation to refer to revisions starting from the head of a branch (or use the revision number directly):

```
bzr branch . ../import-patches -r last:2
```

Then, go to the new branch directory and apply your patches (bzr patch may need the `-p/--strip` option):

```
pushd ../import-patches
for p in 1 2 3; do
    bzr patch /path/to/"${p}".patch
    bzr commit -m "apply patch #${p}"
done
```

Now, go back to your original branch directory and merge. You'll need to commit the merge in a separate step:

```
popd
bzr merge ../import-patches
bzr commit
```

Note that each branch will have a standalone repository, unless you setup a shared repository with `bzr init-repo`. A shared repository is just a directory with revision data stored in its `.bzr` subdirectory and other subdirectories containing individual branches (including nested subdirectories); those branches will store all common revisions in the shared repository. If you are familiar with `git-new-workdir`, this is similar to the main repository being a Git repository without a working tree, and each subdirectory being a working tree initialized with `git-new-workdir` and associated with a separate branch.

Co-located branches allow you to have multiple branches in the same directory; this requires the `colo` plugin for Bzr 2.5.x; co-located branches are supposed to be a core feature for 2.6, but may not be fully stable yet.

Comment: Thank you for relating the `bzr` commands to `git`, that was very helpful.